# Filtering nested lists inside a dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I've got an object in Swift that is a dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, String[]>`. I'd like to be able to filter the `String[]` array whilst maintaining the dictionary structure.

```
let list: Dictionary<String, String[]> = [
    "Vegetables" : [ "Carrot", "Potato" ],
    "Fruit" : [ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" ]
]
```

I'd like to be able to filter for everything containing an "O", and end up with something that looks like this:

```
[
    "Vegetables" : [ "Carrot", "Potato" ],
    "Fruit" : [ "Orange" ]
]
```

To filter the arrays, I've been doing this:

```
["Carrot", "Potato"].filter { ($0 as NSString).containsString("o") }
```

However, the part I'm struggling with now is mapping over the dictionary - because then I can preserve the key and call that filter function on the value. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in a `for in` loop:

```
for (key, array) in list {
    list[key] = array.filter { ($0 as NSString).containsString("o") }
}
```

You can also add your own map method to Dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func map(f: (KeyType, ValueType) -> ValueType) -> [KeyType:ValueType] {
        var ret = [KeyType:ValueType]()
        for (key, value) in self {
            ret[key] = f(key, value)
        }
        return ret
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
var filteredList = list.map { $1.filter { ($0 as NSString).containsString("o") } }
```

**Note:** My implementation of `map` on `Dictionary` returns a copy of the dictionary to be more like the `map` method of `Array`

Comment: Aha yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! And I'd forgotten about extensions too - I was expecting to see a `map` method on Dictionary, so this is really useful.

Comment: Hi Can you please tell me how you have implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate it and filter in 1 go. I just made list a variable instead of a const to make it simpler. Here is the code:

```
//it's a variable
var list: Dictionary<String, String[]> = [
    "Vegetables" : [ "Carrot", "Potato" ],
    "Fruit" : [ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" ]
]


for (key, array) in list {
    list[key] = array.filter({
        (x : String) -> Bool in
        return !(x.rangeOfString("o", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil).isEmpty)
        })
}
NSLog("%@", list)
```

The output will be :

```
{
    Fruit =     (
        Orange
    );
    Vegetables =     (
        Carrot,
        Potato
    );
}
```